# Sencha Architect getting Design View error (Sencha Architect 3.2 & extJS 5.1)

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I have a container having two fields and I have defined a setValue method on the container.
**This works nicely on browser but it breaks the design view capacity of sencha Architect.**

This is the design View error when you click on refresh :

> Cannot bind value on xds.dtype.co.. missing setValue method.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.tresholdBarVal', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
alias: 'widget.tresholdbarval',

requires: [
    'MyApp.view.tresholdBarValViewModel',
    'MyApp.view.tresholdBarValViewController',
    'Ext.form.field.Number',
    'Ext.slider.Multi'
],

controller: 'tresholdbarval',
viewModel: {
    type: 'tresholdbarval'
},

layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    align: 'middle'
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        flex: 0.65,
        reference: 'num',
        margin: '0 10 0 0',
        fieldLabel: 'Label',
        labelWidth: 60,
        readOnly: true,
        decimalPrecision: 1
    },
    {
        xtype: 'multislider',
        flex: 0.8,
        reference: 'bar',
        width: '',
        fieldLabel: 'Label',
        hideLabel: true,
        readOnly: true,
        constrainThumbs: false,
        minValue: -100,
        values: [
            -100,
            0,
            100
        ],
        listeners: {
            change: 'onMultisliderChange'
        }
    }
],

setValue: function(data) {
            bar = this.lookupReference('bar');
            num = this.lookupReference('num');
            bar.setValue(data);
            num.setValue(data[1]);
},


});
```

try to use a mixin with no success :
           mixins: [
                    'Ext.form.field.Base',
            ],

NOTE:

bar.setValue, num.setValue are the methods defined in extJs (on numberfield and multislider)

You can only reproduce the problem on Sencha-architect.
 Try this simple code to create instance :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.test', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
alias: 'widget.test',

requires: [
    'MyApp.view.tresholdBarVal',
    'Ext.panel.Panel',
    'Ext.form.FieldSet'
],

items: [
    {
         xtype: 'tresholdbarval',
         bind: {
             value: [ -99,0, 99 ],
                }
     },
 ]
```

Comment: Can you post the call to `setValue(data)`? Or create a Sencha Fiddle? Can you add a 'default value' in the declaration of the `numberfield` to test?

Comment: May not help you, but just yesterday I wasted 3 hours because SA designer wasnt showing my screens and constantly gave an error "Duplicate component id '<idname>'". Whatever I do, restart SA, I almost recreated the entire screen. But this morning I restarted my PC and BANG... no issues at all. Same code as yesterday. SA Sucks.